# Bootstrap typeahead does not work

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I have included this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href= "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
```

then there is input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" class="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" 
       data-items="4" data-source="['aaa','bbb','ccc']" placeholder="Find customer" />
```

Nothing happens. No error, no suggested items. Why is that? How could  I fix it?

I downloaded bootstrap3-typeahead.js form there: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery "autocomplete" instead: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/